# Divergent paths for post scarcity evolution

Tags: evolution, eugenics

I have a highly advanced race of god like beings that decided a few hundred thousand years ago to stick a bunch of man-kind's early ancestors into habitats that were designed to manipulate their evolution in various ways.

One experiment they conducted was trying to preparing a race for post scarcity.
While this sounds a bit counter intuitive since post scarcity seems like an idealized end goal, in this setting, it usually results in runaway population growth which causes the following issues:

1 - [Behavioral Sink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavioral_sink): Mental illness becomes rampant as society becomes too dense for people to acclimate to social pressures.

2 - Unregulated Developmental System Drift: Genetic degradation that happens from not culling the weak.

3 - Post scarcity can't scale indefinitely: Just because you can automate all industries and the creation of industries does not mean that those industries do not have environmental consequences.  Scarcity always catches up to a run-away population and when it does, it's usually in the form of a mass extinction level collapse.

So, the gods made two worlds as experiments to solve for post-scarcity collapse issues.  Both of these races were put into a sort of "rat utopia" scenario where their environments were intended to naturally provide enough food and resources to guide their evolution in preparation for a post scarcity society, but something about their worlds differed enough to result in two very different solutions to the post scarcity problem.

**Race A** evolved an extremely elevated sense of social consciousness and altruism where by they have become pathologically adverse to excessive behaviors.  As such they keep their population and exploitation of resources in check through responsible decision making.

**Race B** evolved to be extra greedy, prideful, and vain.  They solved the overpopulation issue by becoming so adversarial that any time they try forming large societies that it ends in violent genocidal conflicts that cull the population back down to sustainable numbers.

**How did the gods design these two habitats differently to stimulate such different outcomes?**

*The best answer is the smallest difference the gods could have planned out between these worlds where each solution would have likely happened as they intended (not just two random outcomes from the same setup)*

Comment: (1) Could you please elaborate what is the meaning of the phrase "overpopulation issue" in a post-scarcity setting? (2) Could you please elaborate how the environment could possibly "provide all the resources they could possibly need"? For example, how does the environment provide exquisite counterpoint compositions and masterful interpretations of the same? How does it provide ingenious adventure novels? How does it provide continuously changing clothing fashions? How does it provide an endless supply of (tanned, trimmed and tailored) mink fur?

Comment: @AlexP I tried to keep the exact boundaries of that a bit vague on purpose to allow for some variation in answers.  The point is to create a species that will not just take a post scarcity solution and exploit it until scarcity becomes a problem again. Their environment does not need to be truly post scarcity, it just needs the features necessary to prepare them for a future where fully automated industrialization of everything would not cause them to population boom until the scarcity comes back with a vengeance.

Comment: If the difference is that Race A has Budism Mantras that grow on trees and Race B does not have any plants that can even be used for writing or something out of the box like that, then I did not want to specify such options away by overly defining their environments.

Comment: That is not what the question says. The question says explicitly "post scarcity" and "provide all the resources they could possibly need". Please edit the question to reflect what is your true intention.

Comment: Note that your point 1 assumes that space is scarce. Note that your point 2 assumes that advanced medical treatmets are scarce. Note that your point 3 assumes that environmental resources are scarce. None of those assumption is valid in a post scarcity society; space is not scarce: the universe is very very very large; advanced medical treatments capable of correcting genetic defects will of course be widely available; and I don't see why we'd run out of resources when the universe is so big and full of energy and source materials. Post scarcity implies *by definition* that nothing is scarce.

Comment: A setup that could be called post scarcity for a population of 1e10 life forms will not be post scarce for 1e20 or 1e30 life forms.  To a Kardashev Type IV civilization, even the entire universe has its limits, but as a Type III civilization they would have considered themselves quite post scarcity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Chimpanzee method vs bonobo method.**

https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/bonobo-sex-and-society-2006-06/

> The species is best characterized as female-centered and egalitarian
>   and as one that substitutes sex for aggression. Whereas in most other
>   species sexual behavior is a fairly distinct category, in the bonobo
>   it is part and parcel of social relations--and not just between males
>   and females.

Your adversarial primates are descended from chimpanzees, in which the society structure and reproductive politics are based on violence and the threat of violence.  Those individuals with the greatest capacity for violence of all sorts have the greatest access to resources and the highest fitness.

Your altruistic primates are descended from bonobos, in which the society structure is based on lots and lots of consensual sex.  Those individuals who were the friendliest and the best lovers had greatest access to resources (which they shared) and the highest fitness.

Answer (score 2):

You are working with contradictory forces in this question.  Evolution involves the survival of the fittest while utopias ensure survival for all.  In a post scarcity environment there is not survival challenge to focus natural change towards a particular definition of fitness.  Therefore you get biological entropy rather than evolution.  The change still occurs but every change, no matter how detrimental it might have been in a natural environment, will have no effect (positive or negative) on the survival of the individual organism.

When society provides for all...  all survive.

...and that is not necessarily a good thing; especially over evolutionary periods of time.

The aberrant behavior observed during rodent utopia experiments is mild compared to the depravity which human creativity could bring in a "no choice can threaten survival" environment.

In fact, human depravity would soon replace resource scarcity as the survival threat needed for evolution.  I would expect that this inevitable depravity is what will drive your test subject into Race B behavior (gathering resources to defend themselves from each other instead of from the environment).

Later, once this selfishness provided islands of isolation where personal defenses and weaponry could be built, the strongest individuals may emerge to either dominate or defend weaker individuals.  Depending on the disposition of those strong leaders, the culture might evolve along Race A lines but I see no specific evolutionary force which would require that path to be taken.

Answer (score 2):

***Religion:***   These are gods, so what's important to gods? Worshippers. The two worlds can start with exactly the same conditions (maybe even identical individuals?) but they are intelligent beings of faith.

- In the Altruism world, the followers know the purpose of the course is to encourage cooperation and good will. Therefor, they developed a culture of cooperation and good will. Without the gods needing to intervene, people knowing the gods are watching follow the will of their gods and develop a society based on moral principles. Individuals defying the will of the gods are selected against (imprisoned without reproducing). The church looms large (and likely oppressively) in the life of the people. It is the equivalent of a religious Maoist utopia.
- In the deterministic world, the people know why they are there - to show the gods they can be strongest in their quest to create superior people. They set their faces like flint, like Krupp steel, and brutally exterminate those not fulfilling the will of the gods. There are always some who are weaker than others, even among the strong, so you kill the weakest child, or family, or race, or society. And what better way to decide who is weak than conflict?